# JavaCamera2View enable flash opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv, javacameraview

I am currently using JavaCameraView to enable flash. Unfortunately the APIs of camera1 have been deprecated and therefore I am forced to switch to JavaCamaera2View. The problem is that I can't enable the flash because I don't have access to the camera like in JavaCameraView. 
Do you have any solutions?

This is my code now

```
public class CustomCamera extends JavaCameraView implements PictureCallback {
    private String mPictureFileName;
    public CustomCamera(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public List<String> getEffectList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();
    }
    public boolean isEffectSupported() {
        return (mCamera.getParameters().getFlashMode() != null);
    }
    public String getEffect() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getFlashMode();
    }
    public void setEffect(String effect) {
        mCamera.getParameters();
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(effect);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }
    public List<Size> getResolutionList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    }
    public void setResolution(int w, int h) {
        disconnectCamera();
        mMaxHeight = h;
        mMaxWidth = w;
        connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public Size getResolution() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    }

    public void takePicture(final String fileName) {
        this.mPictureFileName = fileName;
        // Postview and jpeg are sent in the same buffers if the queue is not empty when performing a capture.
        // Clear up buffers to avoid mCamera.takePicture to be stuck because of a memory issue
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

        // PictureCallback is implemented by the current class
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

        // Write the image in a file (in jpeg format)
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFileName);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
        }

    }

    public void cameraRelease() {
        if(mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use CameraX: https://developer.android.com/training/camerax

For example you can use this: https://github.com/JDroidCoder/Camera2
This lib have flash function here: https://github.com/JDroidCoder/Camera2/blob/master/camera2/src/main/java/jdroidcoder/ua/camera2/CameraActivity.kt

Comment: But do I have to create a custom camera and do I have to extend JavaCameraView and then implement camerax there?

Comment: you can use JavaCameraView, or if want create custom. This is very flexible

Comment: ok, so can i use both javacameraview and camerx in single activity? are there conflicts?